# Update multiple rows with different values in a single SQL query- SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing like below. It updates required rows properly but it also updates other rows with NULL in "UserID" column in Testcases_projects table.

Where am I going wrong?

-- To update userID in Projects table with userID from cycle table

```
WITH tempdata(TPID, UserID) AS
(
   SELECT tc.Testcases_ProjectsID, tc.AssignedTo 
   FROM dbo.TestCases_Cycles tc 
   INNER JOIN dbo.TestCases_Projects tp 
   ON tp.TestCases_ProjectsID = tc.Testcases_ProjectsID 
   AND tp.UserID<>tc.AssignedTo
   AND tc.CycleID=6733 AND tp.ProjectID=10500
)
UPDATE dbo.TestCases_Projects 
SET UserID=(SELECT tempdata.UserID 
            FROM tempdata 
            WHERE dbo.TestCases_Projects.TestCases_ProjectsID=tempdata.TPID), 
    AssignedOn=GETDATE()
WHERE ProjectID=10500 
AND Testcases_ProjectsID IN (SELECT Testcases_ProjectsID FROM tempdata)
```

Comment: just do UserID is not null in your where clause for update statement

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` clause is referring to a different column from the correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE dbo.TestCases_Projects 
    SET UserID = (SELECT tempdata.UserID 
                  FROM tempdata td
                  WHERE dbo.TestCases_Projects.TestCases_ProjectsID = td.TPID), 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------^
        AssignedOn = GETDATE()
WHERE ProjectID = 10500 AND
      Testcases_ProjectsID IN (SELECT Testcases_ProjectsID FROM tempdata)
--------------------------------------^
```

These should be the same, presumably `TPID`:

```
UPDATE dbo.TestCases_Projects 
    SET UserID = (SELECT tempdata.UserID 
                  FROM tempdata td
                  WHERE dbo.TestCases_Projects.TestCases_ProjectsID = td.TPID), 
        AssignedOn = GETDATE()
WHERE ProjectID = 10500 AND
      Testcases_ProjectsID IN (SELECT td.TPID FROM tempdata td);
```

Why does your original query work when `temptdata.Testcases_ProjectsID` does not exist?  That is due to scoping in SQL.  The condition ends up being interpreted as:

```
      Testcases_ProjectsID IN (SELECT dbo.TestCases_Projects..Testcases_ProjectsID FROM tempdata td);
```

And this is true for all non-`NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as occasional correlated subquery. In your code

```
...
Testcases_ProjectsID IN (SELECT Testcases_ProjectsID FROM tempdata)
```

columns are not prefixed with table names (aliases). So both `Testcases_ProjectsID` are resolved as `TestCases_Projects.Testcases_ProjectsID` because `tempdata` has no such column.

Use explicit aliases, it will keep your code clean and prevent errors like this one. `SELECT td.Testcases_ProjectsID FROM tempdata td` just will not compile and you'll get clear error message instead of unexpected result.